# How to replace a specific item in a GridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a gridView with 8 elements. When any item in the Grid is tapped upon, I am trying to change the color of that specific element of the grid i.e:

for eg: if I tap on the first square the color should change from red to blue of the first square only and the rest should remain red.
This is what my grid looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 Widget grid(context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1, left: 5, right: 5),
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisSpacing: 15,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
              8,
              (index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        offset: Offset(0, 0),
                        spreadRadius: 0,
                        blurRadius: 0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    child: GridTile(
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          scratchCardDialog(context, scratchReward);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `_currentIndex` property like code below to change color of selected card in `setState` method:

```
    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TestState createState() => _TestState();
    }
    
    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      int _currentIndex;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1, left: 5, right: 5),
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisSpacing: 15,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                8,
                (index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
                      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          offset: Offset(0, 0),
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                          blurRadius: 0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                      child: GridTile(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentIndex = index;
                            });
                            scratchCardDialog(context, scratchReward);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color:
                                _currentIndex == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of bool as a `State` member :

```
var cards = List.generate(8, (_) => false)
```

Now, you can set the card's color to `cards[index] ? Colors.blue : Colors.red`

To update the value when the card is clicked, do `setState(() => cards[index] = true);`

If you want it to be revertible : `setState(() => cards[index] = !cards[index]);`